# How to enter password in a popup using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, headless, xserver

I'm writing some watir test cases:

```
browser.goto "http://egauge2592.egaug.es/"
browser.link(:href,"/settings.html").click
browser.text_field(:index,4).set("some text")
browser.button(:id,"save_button").click
```

then a 'Authentication Required' dialogue opens, asking for username and password .

No matter how I tried, I couldn't access the text fields.

I tried `send_keys` and JavaScript.

I also tried `Watir.autoit` but it says undefined method.

I'm using watir on a Ubuntu machine with the FireFox browser.

How to fill in username and password fields of that dialogue box?
I was able to enter username with browser.alert.set but could only set username couldn't access password field.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the popup?

Comment: It is a browser pop-up. When page requires a digest authentication, browser automatically asks for credentials. The pop-up is the same.

Comment: I also tried doing browser.window(:title) method but it didn't recognize any watir methods(text_field). Also tried to use username:password@ before that site for authentication but didn't work

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion on [Alister Scott's blog](http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/27/automatic-firefox-authentication-when-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoauth/)?

Comment: Yeah I read it but I need to test my cases on headless browser on a server which doesn't have any UI. So how can I use add-on's there??

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a firefox plugin to deal with this problem recently. I haven't tried it with headless Firefox, but it might work... worth a try. See the following for details:

http://www.natontesting.com/2012/10/06/firefox-plugin-test-automation-password-manager/

To get it working with watir, try the following:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
#go to a page that won't bring up the authentication dialog...
browser.goto 'http://www.google.co.uk'

#prepare the script...
pass_man_update_script = <<-SCRIPT
var addCredentialsEvent = new CustomEvent("add_credentials_to_passman", {
  detail: {
    host: 'http://secure.example.com',
    username: 'bob',
    password: 'P45sword'
  }
});
window.dispatchEvent(addCredentialsEvent);
SCRIPT

#inject the script into the browser:
browser.execute_script pass_man_update_script

#go to the page that prompts the dialog box...
browser.goto "http://secure.example.com"
#you should now be past the dialog box!
```

Comment: Yeah I tried your solution earlier but I couldn't write relevant code for watir and I'm not that experienced in selenium

Comment: Just updated the question with details on how to use the plugin with watir

Comment: it's not working with/without that code, needs different code to load plugin for watir

Comment: The above code assumes that the plugins have already loaded... see the answer to this question for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6564780/275673

Comment: this isn't working the alert for uname and paddword still pops up and settings don't get saved, I was able to set uname field by browser.alert.set but could not access password field

Comment: Does the dialog box look like the one in this article's screenshot?: http://www.natontesting.com/2012/10/06/firefox-plugin-test-automation-password-manager/

Comment: title is same then message it says "A username and password are being requested by egauge2592.egaug.es. The site says: "eGauge Administration"" and then the same it is digest authentication

Answer (score 2):

I use watir-webdriver instead and this (http://watirwebdriver.com/basic-browser-authentication/) works for me.

Comment: nope it won't work cause I'm using browser in headless mode and I don't know how to set profile in headless mode

Comment: This trick should work in headless mode assuming your site is using 
"basic http authentication" (and your descriptions make it sound like it is). Have you actually tried it?  It has nothing to do with a profile.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your basic auth credentials in the url:

```
browser.goto "http://user:pass@egauge2592.egaug.es/"
```

Comment: its a digest authentication so it won't work.
BTW I tried that too as mentioned in a comment above

Comment: It should work fine with digest auth. Double check the username/password.

Comment: @pguardiario It works in case of digest-authentication. But, here in our case the problem is service requires `realm` string as well while encoding username and password together. Any idea how to provide it in URL itself ?

Comment: What happens is the browser receives an authentication request including the realm and possible a nonce, etc. You don't need to worry about that. By sending credentials in the url, the browser will automatically send the appropriate credentials, including a hashed password that includes the realm when that is appropriate (in the case of digest auth)

Comment: No, the auth response sends the realm and the browser sends it back automatically.

Comment: @uday it's probably something silly. If you post credentials you will get help otherwise you need to solve it yourself.