# Dummy UI or how to run sikuli in headless mode

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver, headless, sikuli

I'm doing test automation when I faced a problem a digest authentication I'm using watir for my automation, watir couldn't access the alert window which demands username and password, watir  with its browser.alert.set method can only access username field.
I found a solution in sikuli but it needs UI and I need to run this test case on server which doesn't have any UI,I'm using headless in watir test cases can I have something like headless browser in UI to run this test case, like a dummy UI or something or how to run sikuli in headless mode.
Or any solution on my other question [How to enter password in a popup using watir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710287/how-to-enter-password-in-a-popup-using-watir)

Answer (score 2):

All I know is here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/118598

I assume you **need** a view of the desktop, as Sikuli works visually recognizing objects, so there is no point running it in a headless environment.

Comment: Forgive the necrosis, but just a counterpoint: I'm looking to get UI tests running inside a continuous integration setup, which means that the tests do need to be able to run "headless". Looks like there's been some work on that here: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/248704#comment-1

Answer (score 0):

I already use sikuli in headless mode.

**Windows:**  see my [answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/9683/8552).

**Ubuntu:** try Xvfb.